# Newrelic install problem in mac os when I downloaded it on my labtop

Tags: newrelic

I have the following error messages when I tried to install the newrelic agent on my mac labtop.

```
ramirami-pc:sclee-newrelic sclee01$ curl -Ls https://download.newrelic.com/install/newrelic-cli/scripts/install.sh | bash && sudo NEW_RELIC_API_KEY=NRAK-ESS4YM4HY82QYQJX8CX5EFBUS09 NEW_RELIC_ACCOUNT_ID=4100240 /usr/local/bin/newrelic install
Password:
WARNING Failed to connect to the New Relic platform. 
WARNING If you need to use a proxy, consider setting the HTTPS_PROXY environment variable, then try again. 
WARNING More information about proxy configuration: https://github.com/newrelic/newrelic-cli/blob/main/docs/GETTING_STARTED.md#using-an-http-proxy 
WARNING More information about network requirements: https://docs.newrelic.com/docs/new-relic-solutions/get-started/networks/ 
FATAL Get "https://infra-api.newrelic.com/v2": x509: certificate signed by unknown authority
```

I tried to download certificate (CA) `from https://www.digicert.com/kb/digicert-root-certificates.htm#g5roots` but the result is same.

When I launched the ec2 instance with ubuntu, it downloaded newrelic without the above error and it connected.

How to resolve it?

Any help will be appreciated.

Thanks.